# How we can make a DIV clickable by using the link from another div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i m working with wordpress, there is a product section in which i want to put a link on the image also instead of the title of product, so what i want is, i want to make the image div clickable by using the product title link which is in the second link

This is for a wordpress work, i have tried to find the files where i can change the code, but didn't found, so now i want to resolve it using jquery or any method you suggest

```
<div class="product"></div>
<div class="product-title">
    <a class="title" href="url">
</div>
```

Comment: Where you have the code to display the image just wrap that in than anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on) and [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest) like so:

```
$(".product").on("click", function() {
  window.location = $(this).closest(".product-title").find(".title").attr("href");
});
```

Comment: what if there is no class assigned to the a href?

Comment: Then just use `.find("a")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="product"></div>
<div class="product-title">
    <a class="title" href="url" onclick="PerformAction()">
</div>
```

---

// in Js or Jquery

```
function PerformAction()
{
  // Your Logic to perform further operations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the href in the data attribute like so:

```
<div class="product" data-product_url="url"></div>
<script>
    $('.product').on('click', function () {
        window.location = $(this).data('product_url');
    });
</script>
```